# LuaLaTeX returns illegal unit of measure for .tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, matlab2tikz

I have a large graph generated from matlab2tikz (~1.3mb) that I am trying to compile. Latex gives me out of memory errors so I am trying LuaLaTeX. The problem is LuaLaTeX gives me an error: `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).` pointing to line 37030.

If I increase tex's memory then I can compile the document fine. But I would like to try using LuaLatex anyway. The .tikz file I am trying is uploaded here (please note it is large ~1.3 MB, and may lag your browser):

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7e10ab5a663e9e3367f8

Note that line 37030 is the 2nd last line, the `\end{axis}`

(mods - is this the right place for files like this?)

Once the file is saved as a .tikz (or .tex) I am importing it with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\begin{document}
\input{myfile.tex}
\end{document}
```

I can plot less data sets and it will eventually work in both latex and LuaLaTeX. I dont want to downsample because each individual curve is only made of 172 points.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't found what's wrong, but when I ignore all those errors (about 10 of them), the graph looks good.

Comment: @ Malipivo Hmm, how would I go about ignoring errors? I am using the LuaLaTeX compile option from Texmaker. In the configuration that is defined as `lualatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` Thanks

Comment: That should work, in theory. I ran `lualatex yourfile.tex` and I hit Enter several times (TL2013, Windows). I only added `amsmath` package to the preamble as there is `\text` command.

Comment: A tip for solvers to get that file: `wget -O myfile.txt https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/7e10ab5a663e9e3367f8/raw/f502f17b15f806d622ce3c4eadd36f36aedaad6f/gistfile1.txt`

Comment: Oh thanks, It actually compiled the pdf despite the errors. For some reason I didn't think it did. Oh well, thanks for your help. Still not sure why it gives those errors but it works.

Comment: Are you sure that it's worth displaying 1.3MB of plot information in one plot? I'm 100% convinced that nobody is going to see any difference if you remove a good portion of it.

Comment: You are probably right. As you can see from the answer I want it to smoothly go through the spectrum of the colors. But I will try removing every 3rd, 5th, 7th etc to see the effect. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Only workaround, not a real solution

I haven't found the source of this problem, but ignoring errors works. I downloaded file with:

> wget -O myfile.txt https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/7e10ab5a663e9e3367f8/raw/f502f17b15‌​f806d622ce3c4eadd36f36aedaad6f/gistfile1.txt

I added `amsmath` package as the generated file contains `\text` command. I added `\nonstopmode` command at the beginning of the file and I ran:

> lualatex mal-plot.tex

I haven't done much, but it works for the OP. I enclose the TeX code and a preview of the graph.

```
%! lualatex mal-plot.tex
%wget -O myfile.txt https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/7e10ab5a663e9e3367f8/raw/f502f17b15f806d622ce3c4eadd36f36aedaad6f/gistfile1.txt
\nonstopmode
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\begin{document}
\input{myfile.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]